# Is there any way to separate py and pyc files while building Django project using pybuilder

Tags: python, django, pybuilder

I was trying to build a Django project using pybuilder where I need to separate the pyc files and resource files. This is regarding protecting the source code, I know we can achieve this by the licencing mechanism. Our requirement is distributed the pyc file to the client instead of actual py file.

Comment: Source code is trivially retrievable from pyc files. The way to protect your IP is via licensing, not by hiding the source code.